# Linux not connecting to OpenSSH Server in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, openssh

I had configured `OpenSSH` server in `Windows`. And added the public key inside `authorized_keys` file `<<Users>>\.ssh` directory. When I connect from Linux maching using `SSH`, it is throwing the below error.

Any Ideas? Do I missing any configuration?

```
 ****USAGE WARNING****

This is a private computer system. This computer system, including all
related equipment, networks, and network devices (specifically including
Internet access) are provided only for authorized use. This computer system
may be monitored for all lawful purposes, including to ensure that its use
is authorized, for management of the system, to facilitate protection against
unauthorized access, and to verify security procedures, survivability, and
operational security. Monitoring includes active attacks by authorized entities
to test or verify the security of this system. During monitoring, information
may be examined, recorded, copied and used for authorized purposes. All
information, including personal information, placed or sent over this system
may be monitored.

Use of this computer system, authorized or unauthorized, constitutes consent
to monitoring of this system. Unauthorized use may subject you to criminal
prosecution. Evidence of unauthorized use collected during monitoring may be
used for administrative, criminal, or other adverse action. Use of this system
constitutes consent to monitoring for these purposes.
```

and then

```
Connection closed by <<ip_address>>
```

Comment: what do you see in the server log?

Comment: Where it will be?

Comment: This is from event viewer sshd: PID 14296: Connection closed by ipaddress port 48671

Answer (score 0):

Try first debugging the ssh session with verbose mode enabled:

```
$ ssh -v <address>
```

Also, check file permissions of the keys; that you've added the public key correctly. See this guide for instance:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Comment: key_load_public: no Such file or directory

Comment: Then ssh obviously cannot access the file. See if it as correctly added by reading Step Three in that link. Also, change to -vvv for increased verbosity if needed.

Comment: That is for Linux and I am configuring in windows. Can you help ?

Comment: I could not see this command ssh-copy-id

Comment: Read https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_public_key#openssh

Comment: At last it is prompting for private password debug1: Next authentication method: password

<<user>>@<<ipaddress>>.private's password:

Comment: Do you able to get anything on this?

Comment: When UNIX Server needs to connect to Windows Servers? Who needs to share the public keys to whom ? Can you clarify this?